# How to correctly pass scroll position from Android into Libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm making some sort of a game and I have `RecyclerView` with several `TextView`s that I can scroll or move around inside my Android.

Then, above that I have `Libgdx` game running inside transparent fragment, that pass down all the touches to the Android.

I want to create and move this TextView's and also I want some rigid squares to move inside my Libgdx game, so objects can collide with them.

So, Android part is:

```
TextView t = new TextView();
t.setOffset(x,y);
```

Libgdx part is this:

```
BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
bodyDef.bullet = true;
bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.KinematicBody;
bodyDef.position.set(x, y);
```

TextView's can scroll and bodyDefs should also change their position. TextView's can move out of the screen, and bodyDefs should be recycled.

I've noticed that render() method use different thread than main, I suppose I need some sort of syncronization to make it work.

What data structure I should use? What is the general principle of updating bodyDefs from another thread?

Thanks.